# My .css will not link to .html

Tags: html, css

I know this question has been asked alot as I've compared multiple threads to my own code, but I'm still stumped.

My code is as follows:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>R H Y T H M /// U N I T E D</title>
  <link href=“style.css” type=“text/css” rel=“stylesheet”>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>RHYTHM UNITED</h1>
  <a href=“main.html”>Enter</a>
</body>

</html>

****CSS**separate file called style.css***

h1 {
    color: #fa1834;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

Both files within a folder called "Website" on my desktop.

My attempts at fixing this code are as follows:
-Adding a / before the > in the link tag.

-changing to href="/style.css", then I tried href="website/style.css"

Going into chrome->developer I can see that the .css is not linking at all. So my .css code isn't the issue, at least not yet.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried disabling the cache? In chrome, right click > inspect element > Network tab > disable cache

Comment: Just gave it a shot, although it didn't make any changes. I right clicked the page window when doing it, I'm not sure if "inspect element" -> disable cache is a per-page basis, or universal for all of chrome. I also cmd-r since I'm not sure if it applies until doing so.

Just like to add I'm using "Brackets" if it makes any difference. Originally I was using textedit, but I saw it was saving as HTML 4.0something so I figured I'd get an updated editor.

Comment: is this on windows or linux , MAC? depending the file name may be case sensitive, but if both are in the same directory, and you have the case correct it should work as you have it. As should this
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">`

Answer (score 1):

What text/code editor are you using?

You double-quotes seem to be causing the issue.
I created your setup locally myself and experienced the same issue - until I changed the quotes - you can even use single quotes for the sake of testing.

For the sake of learning - use a 'decent' text editor like 'sublime text', or notepad++ (if on windows).

Copy and try this HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>R H Y T H M /// U N I T E D</title>
  <link href='style.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>RHYTHM UNITED</h1>
  <a href='main.html'>Enter</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can use double quotes, they just need to be straight double quotes instead of slanted ones

Comment: Yeah I realise that, but for the sake of making it obvious I changed to single quotes.

Comment: EDIT: Got it working! I just had to delete the s in styles.css when I copy pasted your code. THANK YOU! Who knew a little thing like the brackets would have caused this headache. Is there a way to give rep or anything on this forum?
Cheers

Comment: You can up-vote my answer, and you can select the answer as 'accepted'.